# Как создать проверку на наличие пустой строки

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

Приветствую! Не получилось у меня найти на официальном источнике подобных примеров. У меня есть код, который проходится по jsonовскому файлу и выводит определённым образом информацию. Возможно ли сделать в строчке  проверку, что бы если строка не пустая, выводилась надпись "фото" между атрибутами "а", если же пустая, то так же и остаётся пустой. Заранее благодарен!

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="countryApp">
<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <title>Монитор готовности</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.7/angular.min.js"></script>
 <script>
  var countryApp = angular.module('countryApp', []);
  countryApp.controller('CountryCtrl', function ($scope, $http){
   $http.get('test.json').success(function(data) {
    $scope.countries = data;
   });
  });
 </script>
<style>
progress::-ms-fill {   border: none; }
progress[value="100"]::-ms-fill {   background-color: #aaff00; }
</style>

</head>
<body ng-controller="CountryCtrl">
 <h2>Монитор готовности объектов</h2 >
 <table class="table table-striped">
  <tr>
   <th>ID</th>
   <th>Объекты</th>
   <th>Процент готовности</th>
   <th>Ввод в эксплуатацию</th>
   <th>Текущее состояние</th>
      <th>Фото</th>
  </tr>
  <tr ng-repeat="country in countries ">
   <td>{{country.ID}}</td>
   <td>{{country.Obj}}</td>
   <td><meter id='p' max='100' value={{country.proc_gotov}}></meter>{{country.proc_gotov}}%</td>
   <td>{{country.vvod}}</td>
   <td>{{country.current}}</td>
   <td><a href="{{country.photo}}"></a></td>
            

<!-- begin snippet: js hide: false console: true babel: false -->
```

Comment: какая именно строка должна быть пустой?

Comment: там где a href="{{country.photo}}". если в country.photo есть линк на картинку, то получается вроде  <td><a href="{{country.photo}}">Фото</a></td>. Если нет, остаётся такой же

Comment: @ДмитрийСавенко смотрите в сторону директивы https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngIf
Если же вам нужно, чтобы при отсутствии url ничего не отображалось, тогда лучше сделать через https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngShow

Comment: @GONG Я добавил дерективу в строку <td ng-show="isshow"><a href="{{country.Photo}}">Фото</td> Но не могу понять, каким образом связать его с тем, есть ли в текущем country.Photo информация или нет

Answer (score 0):

Получилось так реализовать, просто сравнив размер строки с нулём. Заработало! `<td ng-show="isShow=country.Photo.length >0"><a href="{{country.Photo}}">фото</td>`

Comment: зачем присваивать `isShow`? ты же не используешь потом эту переменную

Comment: @Grundy и в правду, присваивание было лишним ))

Answer (score -1):

Ну попробую вот так...

```
<td><a href="{{country.Photo}}">{{country.Photo ? 'фото' : ''}}</td>
```